# Rename files with spaces instead of underscores

Tags: bash

I've got a whole folders of files with names like:

```
super_awesome___[stuff_here]_-_is_cool.ext
super_duper_coolness___[more_stuff_here]_-_look_at_me_cool.ext
```

What's the easiest way, in bash, to rename all of them so the underscores become spaces? There are too many files for me to do this manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will replace multiple `_` with one  for all files named `*.ext`

```
for f in *.ext; do mv $f "$(echo $f | sed 's/_\+/ /g')"; done
```

if you don't want that remove the `\+`

```
for f in *.ext; do mv $f "$(echo $f | sed 's/_/ /g')"; done
```

Comment: I should test before posting code... Now it should be correct

Comment: The original would've replaced all underscores and the following character (so lol_this) with spaces (would be lol his), right?

Comment: @Rob - you are correct

Comment: `mv "$f" "${f//_/ }"`

Comment: Woah woah woah... how did that work, grawity? I understand the echo | sed answer. Does ${f//_/ } basically mean `${f` for all of the $f's, `//_/ }` substitute _ for space?

Comment: @Rob: It's called [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#overview). `${var//x/y}` replaces all instances of `x` with `y` while expanding `$var`. (Note: `${f}` is equivalent to just `$f` - the parens are just delimiters and do not mean "for all of f" or anything like that. You *do* still need a `for f in *.ext` loop.)